# Mysql error : mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, php-7

I have install mysql on digital ocean and trying to connect through php script and I got this error

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in
>   /var/www/waev.in/signup/ajax/send_code.php on line 9 Failed to connect
>   to MySQL: Connection refused

What can be the issue :

**my php script**

```
<?php
    include '../func/sms_function.php';

    $mysql_host='{ip}';
    $mysql_user='root';
    $mysql_pass='********';
    $my_db='wesearch_waev_user';

    $con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be

```
  $mysql_host="localhost";// for local server
```

Or

```
 $mysql_host="$ip";// if database is in remote and IP is stored in $ip
```

Comment: I did the same @Rishi

Comment: @SaMeEr  Did you try both option ?

Comment: but what if I am accessing database from another server that time I have to have use ip. will it work then ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the port you are using on the server. MySQL needs to be running on the port 3306